# Angular2: how to apply two or more validators to the same control?

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms, custom-validators, angular2-formbuilder

I'm creating a form with Angular2 and I created two custom validators for email address field.

The first validator checks for email validity, the second (async) validator checks if email address already exists on database.
In addition I would like to add a third validator for another verification.

Here is my code:

```
'email': ['', [validateEmail(), thirdValidator()], asyncValidator]
```

The behaviour that I want is the following:
Only when the first validator validates the control, the second validator should start. And only when the second validator terminates then the third validator can start its validation.

How to reach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Validators.compose` method should do the job, example:

```
   let formControls = {
        'oldPassword': new FormControl({ value: ''}),
        'newPassword': new FormControl({ value: ''}, Validators.compose([customValidator1, customValidator2]), customAsyncValidator)
    };
```

Composed validators work simultaneously, meaning we can have multiple errors on the control at the same time (each validator attaches its own error if validation failed). If we need to have only one error on the control at a time, we can 'chain' validators by checking the  status of the previous validation before performing next one. Something like this:

```
    let customValidator2 = (ctrl: FormControl): any => {
        if(ctrl.hasError('customValidationError1')) {
            // there is the error attached by customValidator1, 
            // skip executing customValidator2 (nullify its error)
            return null;
        }

        let isInvalid = true; // some condition...

        return isInvalid ? { customValidationError2: true } : null;
    }
```

This way we can accomplish 'ordering' the validators by their priority for example.

Comment: I didn't know that method... anyway it seems not be the answer to my question: `Compose multiple validators into a single function that returns the union of the individual error maps.` Isn't it like to use `[validateEmail(), thirdValidator()]` ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Validators do not work in sequence they've been provided. We can have multiple errors on one field ofc. However we can manually rein them as in the example above.

Comment: Ok, that's fine for me. Thank you. Anyway it seems that validators in sequence work in AND. Is this right? In addition, can you tell me what is the difference between putting validators in sequence and using `compose` method?

Comment: Either way they work simultaneously I think, there shouldn't be difference, however I will check it to make sure.

Comment: In your solution you write `return null` if previous validator fails. `return null` means that the validation for the second validation was ok. Is this right? Besides, could your solution work with async validator as well?

Comment: Yes, it also means that the ctrl isn't validated (since the first validation shows the error, we want to skip the second validation by marking it valid). I guess the same logic could be applied to async validators.

Comment: I tried combining validators and async validators but thet seem not to work. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Do you have your attempt near at hand?

Comment: Yes, can i show my files on pastebin? Here is my custom validator: http://pastebin.com/Q9GjbK43 and here is my custom async validator: http://pastebin.com/z14cmAAe

Comment: Just looking at it, seems ok at first but I would need to create my version in order to debug it.

Comment: Seems that asyncValidator by default isn't performed if synchronous validation failed, so there is no need for the workaround mentioned in the answer when it comes to asyncValidators. Do you pass your asyncValidator as third argument when instantiating FormControl? (new FormControl('', validator, asyncValidator))

Comment: Btw, try editing this plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/nOFYzTdbzbS3PkzFOfpc/ , it's an older version of Angular, but it can give an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and for your support. I do edit your Plunker... please have a look a it: https://plnkr.co/edit/ByjSwHWtRPSGoOUvICCK (I'm sorry... it doesn't work...)

Comment: Here is an updated (working) version: https://plnkr.co/edit/pDMKtdC5PqFttfraOPqf. As you can see it is not the behaviour i expect. Async validator shouldn't start if the sync validators don't pass the test on the input. The same with my custom validator: it shouldn't start if `required` doesn't pass the test.